# Does credit Card debts influence future USA Visiting visa approval?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I had to leave USA for some personal reasons couple of months back. I have around $8000 in debt with three different credit card services. I was unable to pay back due to my unemployment and had to leave the country. I m trying to pay the debt back but the currency differences makes it lot harder to clear the debt. Does this cause any rejections if I try to visit USA next year some time?

Comment: Will you have repaid the debt before you incur visit-related expenditure?

Comment: What is your nationality and do you currently have any valid visas or other status in the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having debt in the US does not automatically prevent you from getting a US visa. Nor will you be arrested at the airport just because you have debt.

On the other hand, one of the things you need to do to get the visa is to show that you can support yourself for your time in the US (without of course working). That becomes much harder to demonstrate if you have substantial debt, regardless of what country that debt is in.

Likewise you have to show that the money you spend on your US visit is reasonable for you to spend given your financial circumstances. You don't state the reason for your wanting to visit the US, or where you are visiting from. but (for example) people with thousands of dollars of debt who are trying to pay it back don't take expensive overseas vacations. On the other  hand if the visit was business related and your employer was paying the costs that would be different.

So the short answer is that the debt is not an automatic barrier, but can be a negative factor in your visa application. How much of a negative factor we cannot determine.

Comment: But how would the US find out about the OP's credit history?  The visa application asks for funds, not debts, and credit bureaus etc are not a part of the government.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Maybe via the OP’s bank statements, if the OP is making repayments that way?

Comment: @Traveller No way! Most people myself included pay for everything with credit cards and pay the credit card off monthly. Huge transfers from my bank account to my credit card mean absolutely nothing.

Comment: The short answer is that your credit card debt in the USA has absolutely no bearing on your visa application. That said the responsible thing to do and/or accrue good karma is do you best to pay back what you owe. Doesn’t mean you should subsist on bread and water though. 

Comment: @user56513 Indeed, I do the same myself. However, it could flag up as a question regarding ability to support themselves during any visit if the OP is making payments to three different USA-issued cards but is not a resident of the USA, especially if the OP’s bank statements also show payments to other credit cards. I guess it could depend on the OP’s overall personal circumstances as to whether any such payments would attract any attention or not.

Comment: @user56513: Realistically, if you have a lot of credit card debt, you probably *don't* have a huge bank account balance (it does not make financial sense to carry a large credit card balance when you have money in the bank), and that's a negative all by itself.

Comment: @Kevin Paying off your balances after your statement posts will show you are carrying a lot of debt while that is not the case.

Comment: @user56513: That is not the situation which OP describes.